# Read/Write to JSON file in root directory of simply markup project

Tags: javascript, json, local

I have a very simple project. It's only local and I don't require it to ever be online. I'm perfectly content running it by opening index.html in chrome. Along with my html, css, and javascript file there is a data.JSON in my root directory of my project. My question is: can I read and write to this file? Or is there a possible alternative to simple data persistence. I've had no luck beating cross origin policy up to this point using $.getJSON.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data;
  var g = $.getJSON('../data.JSON', function(d){
    console.log(d);
    data = d;
  });
  console.log(data)
```

d = proper JSON object,
data = undefined

I have no idea why...

Comment: Add some code snippets to help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript in your case is working only on client side and you cannot modify any file on client's machine.

**Alternative solutions:**

**Use a server**, if you are familiar with javascript, you can use node.js. Though it has a learning curve and you might take some time in learning that.

**Download updated JSON file and replace original file** with this new file. you can create files in javascript and download them on client machine. Then you have to manually replace original file.

Comment: I am familiar with node.js, I was hoping to keep this project super simple. Perhaps thats the only choice i have.